# ASP.NET update panel nested refreshing

Tags: asp.net, triggers, updatepanel

This code is in a user control . and i am providing a sample code structure to get an overview .

```
<Update Panel UpdateMode= "Conditional">
<panel></panel>
<panel>
<button></button>
</panel>
<updatepanel UpdateMode="Conditional"></updatepanel>
</Updatepanel>
```

so when i click a button in the second panel , i am supposed to hide that panel and it is happening but simultaneously the other panels are getting refreshed . what could be the possible reason for that ?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code snippet you may have a couple issues to fix:

1. Make sure you have a `ScriptManager` on the page with `EnablePartialRendering="true"`
2. Correct your markup by making the `<UpdatePanel>` elements [ASP.NET UpdatePanel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.updatepanel(v=vs.110).aspx) controls by prefixing them with "asp:".
3. Add `UpdateMode="Conditional"` to both of your UpdatePanel controls
4. Move the sections you want to update asynchronously into the UpdatePanel controls.

Example

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="MyScriptManager" EnablePartialRendering="true" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="MyUpdatePanel" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="This is a label!"></asp:Label>
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Click Me" />
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

The following article is a great resource to learn more about the UpdatePanel with details on it's capabilities.

[Understanding Partial Page Updates with ASP.NET AJAX](https://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/older-versions-getting-started/aspnet-ajax/understanding-partial-page-updates-with-asp-net-ajax)